# How to generate .proto file from FileDescriptor

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am generating a `protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor`from an XML File to define the interface between different machines. The `FileDescriptor`is really handy to define the protocol and use it for late-binded calls. Now I also want to be able to generate the appropriate `.proto` file but I only found the `DebugString()` method in the C++ implementation [link](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#Descriptor.DebugString.details).

As an easy workaround, I can of course do the `.proto` file generation by hand as done e.g. [here](https://github.com/tranchis/xsd2thrift/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/tranchis/xsd2thrift/marshal/ProtobufMarshaller.java) but that destroys a lot of the convenience of using the `FileDescriptor`class.

The question: Is there an easier way of generating the `.proto` file than doing it by hand? (I wouldn't consider wrapping the C++ class to be a clean solution either)

Comment: *bump* Love to know if anyone has an answer to this :)